# CRUD generated controllers and its actions are not called yii2 advanced

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

Actually after creating controller when I am trying to access via `r=kandyusers` it is throwing 404 error but its working fine with `r=site`
and one what I would like to specify is in my crud generator there is view path don't know why. But where as those I saw in youtube tutorials there is no such element.

[image: screen shot of crud generator]

Answer (score 1):

You should simply try `kandy-users` instead of `kandyusers`

Read more : [Controller class naming](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-controllers.html#controller-class-naming)

> Controller class names can be derived from controller IDs according to
>   the following rules:
>
> - Turn the first letter in each word separated by dashes into upper case. Note that if the controller ID contains slashes, this rule only
>     applies to the part after the last slash in the ID.
> - Remove dashes and replace any forward slashes with backward slashes.
> - Append the suffix Controller.
> - And prepend the controller namespace.

And about the view path in gii, you should try with `@backend/views/kandy-users`

Comment: why does @backend/views/kandy-users required which was not there in yii version 1

Comment: It is not required, but if not set it will default to `@app/views/ControllerID` like in yii1

Answer (score 0):

I tried the Gii code generator in Yii2 advanced app sample and i saw it created all the files in the 'frontend' zone.

It also creates the views under the folder frontend/web which is different from the location where the controller is calling the view.

I recommend you to check every folder/file route shown in the 'preview' option of the Gii, and once you reach the desired folder configuration, check where is the controller searching the view.

Maybe you will need to add this sentence to your crud controller class to make Yii to know here is the desired view, for example in the UserCrudController i have the view under the folder crud/:

```
public function getViewPath()
{
    return Yii::getAlias('@frontend/views/crud/User');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I find it quite confusing so I've prepared a cheatsheet. 
I'm setting up a module for each table so I can use Gii CRUD for the admin.
I'm using Yii2 advanced theme and placing the modules under backend.

Note that controller ID's should be in lower case:

> By default, controller IDs should contain these characters only: English letters in lower case, digits, underscores, hyphens, and forward slashes. For example, article and post-comment are both valid controller IDs, while article?, PostComment, admin\post are not.

table with one word like posts (better to have it in plurals for Gii) are simple.

for tables with more words like post_topic there are at least two ways:

1 - use one word like posttopic (all lowercase)

2 - use module name same as the table name post_topic. Just be aware that when Gii tells you to put in your config file modules section 'post_topic', you should really use 'post-topic'. This option is not neat (uses post_topic for module folder, post-topic for view folder, PostTopic.php for file).

I'll be happy to hear if someone has a better solution as this point is not well documented and all the examples are using one word.

So here is my settings (showing option 2 for multi words table)

```
for one word tables:
module generator
----------------
module class:       backend\modules\posts\Module
module id:          posts
                    update in common\config\main.php

model generator
---------------
table name:         posts
model class:        Posts
namespace:          backend\modules\posts\models
Enable I18n:        checked. Message category: app

CRUD generator
--------------
Model class:        backend\modules\posts\models\Posts
Search model class: backend\modules\posts\models\PostsSearch
Controller class:   backend\modules\posts\controllers\PostsController
View path:          @backend/modules/posts/views/posts
Enable I18n:        checked. Message category: app
Enable pjax:        checked

need to change Users::className() in the models\Posts.php 
\amnah\yii2\user\models\User::className()

Access the crud page: www.example.com/backend/web/posts/posts 


or for two or more words tables:
module generator
----------------
module class:       backend\modules\post_topic\Module
module id:          post_topic

Gii say to use:     'post_topic' => ['class' => 'backend\modules\post_topic\Module',],
But we should use:  'post-topic' => ['class' => 'backend\modules\post_topic\Module',],

model generator
---------------
table name:         post_topic
model class:        PostTopic
namespace:          backend\modules\post_topic\models
Enable I18n:        checked. category: app

CRUD generator
--------------
Model class:        backend\modules\post_topic\models\PostTopic
Search model class: backend\modules\post_topic\models\PostTopicSearch
Controller class:   backend\modules\post_topic\controllers\PostTopicController
View path:          @backend/modules/post_topic/views/post-topic
Enable I18n:        checked. category: app
Enable pjax:        checked

need to change Users::className() in the models\PostTopic.php 
\amnah\yii2\user\models\User::className()

Access the crud page: www.example.com/backend/web/post-topic/post-topic
```